# chrome.idle is undefined in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to implement a simple idle detection in chrome.
I created an extension with this permission:

```
"permissions": [
    "webNavigation",
    "storage",
    "tabs",
    "*://*/*",
    "idle"
],
"background": {
    "scripts": ["js/background.js"]
},
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "run_at": "document_start",
        "matches": [
            "*://*/*"
        ],
        "css": [
            "css/content.css"
        ],
        "js": [
            "js/jquery.min.js",
            "js/content.js"
        ]
    }
]
```

and in content.js

```
$(function () {

  console.log('init idle detection');
   chrome.idle.queryState(5, function(newState){
     //"active", "idle", or "locked"
     if(newState === "idle"){ alert(newState);    }
  });


   ...init other things...

});
```

however, chrome.idle is always undefined.

Comment: According to [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts), content scripts cannot access `idle` API. Use it in background script and communicate with content script via messaging.

Comment: sorry, where exactly? in the official example, it is included in a .js file included in a html opened on click...

Comment: The html opened on click is probably a browserAction popup which is an extension page with chrome-extension:// URL so it can use all the APIs.

Answer (score 2):

According to [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#capabilities), content scripts cannot access `idle` API. Use it in background script (or popup script) and communicate with content script via messaging.

From the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#capabilities):

> Content scripts can access Chrome APIs used by their parent extension
>   by exchanging **messages** with the extension. They can also access the
>   URL of an extension's file with chrome.runtime.getURL() and use the
>   result the same as other URLs.
>
> ```
> //Code for displaying <extensionDir>/images/myimage.png:
> var imgURL = chrome.runtime.getURL("images/myimage.png");  
> document.getElementById("someImage").src = imgURL;
> ```
>
> Additionally,
>   content script can access the following chrome APIs directly:
>
> - i18n
> - storage
> - runtime:
>
>   - connect
>   - getManifest
>   - getURL
>   - id
>   - onConnect
>   - onMessage
>   - sendMessage
>
> **Content scripts are unable to access other APIs directly.**

(Bold type on last line added)